# Calculate Normals Geometry Shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

Im currently writing my own GLSL shaders, and wanted to have smooth shading. The shading worked when i calculated the normals bevore sending them to a VBO, but the problem here is when I implement animations with bone matricies, the normals are not corect.

I am using a geometry shader to calculate the normals, but i cant find out how to smooth them.

Here is my geometry shader:

```
#version 150

layout(triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices=3) out;

in vec2 texCoord0[3];
in vec3 worldPos0[3];

out vec2 texCoord1;
out vec3 normal1;
out vec3 worldPos1;

 void main()
 {

        vec3 n = cross(worldPos0[1].xyz-worldPos0[0].xyz, worldPos0[2].xyz-worldPos0[0].xyz);
        for(int i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++)
        {
             gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position;

             texCoord1 = texCoord0;
             normal1 = n;
             worldPos1 = worldPos0;

             EmitVertex();
        }
}
```

I need the faces next to the face that I calculate the normals for, but i dont know how to get them.

Comment: do you need to recalculate normals each frame?

Comment: Do the normals need to be unit length? i.e., *normalized* ?

Comment: Why are you performing skeletal posing in the geometry shader? Posing is normally done in the vertex shader.

Comment: @BrettHale I normalize them in the fragment shader.

Comment: @datenwolf I have my bone matrices in my fragment shader.

Comment: @fen I have 2 shaders 1 for animated meshes and anotherone for static meshes. For the static meshes i have precalculated normals.

Answer (score 2):

The geometry shader in OpenGL only has access to single triangles and not the whole mesh, so the normal must be calculated from a single triangle.

The usual solution to this problem is to calculate the normals once for each vertex and store them in vertex arrays for easy access. This turns out to be faster and simpler, as you don't need to recalculate anything in shaders.

Comment: There are [adjacency primitive types](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Primitive#Adjacency_Primitives) that allow geometry shaders to access the vertices for adjacent lines / triangles (this information is pulled from the index stream, so if you do not use `glDrawElements (...)` it will not work as expected). If you use one of these primitive types and appropriate indices it is possible, though as you point out the simpler solution for non-parametric geometry is to do this ahead of time.

Comment: I know that i can access the neighbours with triangles_adjacent, but what i dont get is how i have to set up the elementbuffer and vertexbuffer when i use GL32.GL_TRIANGLES_ADJACENT as draw type in glDrawElements.