# OpenGL custom quads have lighting bugs

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to figure out how to write my own primitives like gluSolidCube()..

In the following code I'm drawing 2 quads. One with the help of this method (the red one) and another one - by my own with the help of glBegin()/glEnd() (the blue one).

```
glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(-angleX, 0, 0, 1);
    glRotatef(angleY, 0, 1, 0);

    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glTranslatef(0.6, 0, 0);
    glutSolidCube(1);

    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(-1.2, 0, 0);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5);

        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0.5);

        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5);

        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, -0.5);

        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
        glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0.5);

        glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
        glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
    glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

So as you can see at the following screenshots the lightnings on the red quad is correct unlike the blue one. How to solve this?

[image: screen 1]

[image: screen 2]

Comment: For the minimum code that you have provided, you need normals: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50653/opengl-why-do-i-have-to-set-a-normal-with-glnormal/50656

Comment: @Amadeus this link didn't provide me with a solution. I tried to add before every glVertex() a glNormal(0, 0, 1) and it didn't help...

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL fixed-function lighting won't work correctly without [sensible vertex/face normals](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/git_master/freeglut/freeglut/src/fg_geometry.c#L707).

You need to supply [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656358/calculating-normals-in-a-triangle-mesh), perhaps via `glNormal()`.

Comment: Ok as I understood I need to do more maths. For every plane I need to get a normal vector? Is there some equation for this? Gone googling...